# Does the sizeof operator work in preprocessor #if directives?

Tags: c, sizeof

Can we use the `sizeof` operator in `#if` macros? If yes, how? And if not, why?

Does the `sizeof` operator work in preprocessor `#if` directives?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "define size of operator in macros?"  I'm guessing you're asking if you can use the sizeof operator in preprocessor expressions evaluation in #if?  Is that correct?

Comment: @Eric yes it's correct

Comment: Here's [an amusing answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!original/comp.std.c/A1XTfedHzJk/iQ0GGsavUkgJ) to this. (Dennis Ritchie invented C.)

Comment: You can use `sizeof` in a preprocessor expression, i.e., in a `#if` directive -- but it's just treated as an ordinary identifier and is replaced by `0`.

Comment: @KeithThompson can you please describe the internal process of sizeof operator means how sizeof operator find out the size???

Comment: its working must be something like this 

size_t size = (size_t)(1 + ((X*)0));

Comment: @ Michael Smith what is X representing??

Comment: The X in Michael's comment is the type in `sizeof(X)`.  I'm not convinced that's how it actually works, but the result is the same, because adding 1 to a pointer gives the address of the next element in the (hypothetical) array, and the start address here is 0.  The `sizeof()` operator simply has to know how to compute the size of a type or an expression; it is a requirement of the language specification.  The language doesn't specify how it achieves that.  It depends in part on issues like alignment and padding if you're dealing with structures.

Comment: @VarunChhangani that's method to know size of any data type without using sizeof operator.

Comment: @VarunChhangani: Ignoring VLAs, the result of `sizeof` is computed directly by the compiler. The compiler has to know the size of the type, or the type of the expression, that's the operand of the `sizeof` operator. It replaces the `sizeof` expression with that constant size.

Comment: @MichaelSmith: That behaves like `sizeof` (though it can be applied only to types, not to expressions) -- but it's not useful in understanding how `sizeof` itself is implemented.

Comment: @ Keith Thompson --  Michael Smith told the right way to find out the size of operands but not the told the working of it. By  Michael Smith we can find size of any operands without help of sizeof operator.Is it right??

Comment: @VarunChhangani- That's just the way to implement it as Shashank_jain said i.e. to know size without using sizeof operator. i don't know about internal working of sizeof() operator but i thought may this code and its internal code must be doing something similiar

Comment: @VarunChhangani - i Think You should choose one as ACCEPTED answer for Clarity to coming users and for us !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No; the `sizeof()` operator does not work in C preprocessor conditional directives such as `#if` and `#elif`.

The reason is that the C pre-processor does not know a thing about the sizes of types.

You can use `sizeof()` in the body of a `#define`'d macro, of course, because the compiler handles the analysis of the replacement text and the preprocessor does not.  For example, a classic macro gives the number of elements in an array; it goes by various names, but is:

```
#define DIM(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))
```

This can be used with:

```
static const char *list[] =
{
    "...", ...
};
size_t size_list = DIM(list);
```

What you can't do is:

```
#if sizeof(long) > sizeof(int)  // Invalid, non-working code
...
#endif
```

(The trouble is that the condition is evaluated to `#if 0(0) > 0(0)` under all plausible circumstances, and the parentheses make the expression invalid, even under the liberal rules of preprocessor arithmetic.)

Comment: that's mean we can't use sizeof operator in macros.

Comment: @VarunChhangani: Sure we can. The macro will expand to something that includes the `sizeof` keyword, and the resulting expression will be evaluated normally.

Comment: @ Keith Thompson I have one more doubt that preprocessor work at compile time and expand the source code and  sizeof operator also work at compile time so when both work on compile time why sizeof operator doesn't find the size of any data type through macros???\

Comment: @VarunChhangani: It's because of the way the compiler works in phases, and the preprocessing is done before the source the source is parsed into tokens and tokens are identified as types or keywords (etc.).  Logically, the C pre-processor is run in its entirety before the compiler proper sees anything. The preprocessor completely ignores C keywords; you can have `#define const /* nothing */` and the preprocessor is happy and effectively erases any `const` that appears in the source. You could have a macro with the same name as a C keyword; the preprocessor is OK with that (but no-one else is).

Comment: When you've fully understood it all, you'll know why compiling the following three lines of code produces the warning: (1) `#if sizeof +8  > sizeof +4LL` (2)
`#warning sizeof int 8 larger than size of long long 4` (3)
`#endif`.

Answer (score 6):

A **sizeof()** operator cannot be used in **#if and #elif** line because the preprocessor does not parse type names.

But the expression in **#define** is not evaluated by the preprocessor; hence it is legal in **#define** case.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

//#if sizeof(int) == 4
#if UINT_MAX == 0xffffffffU

typedef int int32;

#endif

//#if sizeof(long) > sizeof(int)
#if ULONG_MAX > UINT_MAX

typedef long int64;

#elif ULLONG_MAX > ULONG_MAX

typedef long long int64;

#endif

int main(void) {
    int64 i64;
    int32 i32;
    printf("%u, %u\n", (unsigned)sizeof(i64), (unsigned)sizeof(i32));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

sizeof will not work in # directives. These operators have not been defined during preprocessing. That is the whole point of *compiling* code. For sizeof to be recognized during preprocessing, you would need another compiler before the, well, compiler.

Comment: which compiler can you describe??

Comment: What? It doesn't matter. sizeof needs to be compiled. It will not compile before compile time which means it cannot be used in # directives. BTW I edited my answer to not include macros. Macros simply get converted to whatever code is written.