# sizeof in preprocessor command doesn't compile with error C1017

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

I want to use preprocessor command to control code executive path. Because in this way can save runtime time.

`#if (sizeof(T)==1` doesn't comple with error: C1017

```
template<typename T>
    class String
    {
    public:
        static void showSize()
        {
#if (sizeof(T)==1) 
            cout << "char\n";
#else
            cout << "wchar_t\n";
#endif
        }
    };

    inline void test()
    {
        String<char>::showSize();
        String<wchar_t>::showSize();
    }
```

Comment: While `sizeof` is a compile-time construct in C++, it's still not part of the preprocessor. If you want a compile-time check use `if constexpr (sizeof(T) == 1)`.

Comment: I don't suppose we can talk you into making that a formal answer, can we?

Comment: @user4581301, actually, you can.

Comment: I'd expect the same code to be generated with or without `constexpr`. The compiler can deal with `if(1)` or `if(0)` and not emit a runtime choice

Comment: [How can I use "sizeof" in a preprocessor macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079243/) [Does the sizeof operator work in preprocessor #if directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176641/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The preprocessor runs before the C++ compiler.  It knows nothing of C++ types; only preprocessor tokens.

While I would expect any decent compiler to optimize away an `if (sizeof(T) == 1)`, you can be explicit about it in C++17 with the new `if constexpr`:

```
template<typename T>
class String
{
public:
    static void showSize()
    {
        if constexpr (sizeof(T) == 1) {
            std::cout << "char\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "wchar_t\n";
        }
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97c3692ff7321186)

Pre C++17 it's a bit less straightforward.  You could use some partial-specialization shenanigans.  It's not particularly pretty, and I don't think it will even be more efficient in this case, but the same pattern could be applied in other situations:

```
template <typename T, size_t = sizeof(T)>
struct size_shower
{
    static void showSize()
    {
        std::cout << "wchar_t\n";
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct size_shower<T, 1>
{
    static void showSize()
    {
        std::cout << "char\n";
    }
};

template<typename T>
class String
{
public:
    static void showSize()
    {
        size_shower<T>::showSize();
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e215e0e1829eb32)

In this case you could directly specialize `String`, but I'm assuming in your real situation it has other members that you don't want to have to repeat.

Answer (score 1):

The C and C++ preprocessor is mostly a glorified (well, not that glorious) text replacement engine.  It doesn't really understand C or C++ code.  It doesn't know `sizeof`, and it doesn't know C or C++ types. (It certainly won't know what `T` from your template class is.)

If you want to do things conditionally on `T` and on `sizeof`, then you'll need to write C++ code to do it (i.e., `if (...)` instead of `#if ...`.)

Comment: This will result in a completely different way.
`#if` happens at compile time
`if()` happens in run-time

you should use `if constexpr(sizeof)` for it to work in compile time.

Keep in mind that if `contsexpr if` is a new feature in C++17

Comment: @EnoshCohen The compiler will likely optimize it out, but it's still a good idea to mention `constexpr`.

Answer (score 0):

As @some-programmer-dude mentioned in the comment, `sizeof` is not part of the preprocessor.

you should use `if constexpr` if you want it to work in compile time.

if you don't care if it happens in compile time or run-time just use a regular `if` statment

keep in mind that `if constexpr` is a new feature in C++17!

Answer (score 0):

btw Borland C++ and Watcom C++ support sizeof() in preprocessor expressions, I do not know whether gcc support it.