# trim for both std::string and std::wstring

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a trim function for std::string,

```
    static string trim(const string &s)
    {
        int ibegin = s.find_first_not_of(" \t\r\n");
        if (ibegin == string::npos)
        {
            return "";
        }

        int iend = s.find_last_not_of(" \t\r\n");

        return s.substr(ibegin, iend - ibegin);
    }
```

I want to adapt it for both string and wstring,

```
template<typename TCHAR>
std::basic_string<TCHAR> trim(const std::basic_string<TCHAR>& s)
{
#if (sizeof(TCHAR)==1) 
    int ibegin = s.find_first_not_of(" \t\r\n");
#else
    int ibegin = s.find_first_not_of(L" \t\r\n");
#endif
...
}
```

But it doesn't compile.
[sizeof in preprocessor command doesn't compile with error C1017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56862962/sizeof-in-preprocessor-command-doesnt-compile-with-error-c1017)

Comment: I think you need some kind of `if constexpr` because the preprocessor runs before the compiler instantiates `#if` directives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TCHAR` is the template argument, not a preprocessor token. Use `if constexpr` instead.

```
template<typename TCHAR>
std::basic_string<TCHAR> trim(const std::basic_string<TCHAR>& s)
{
    int ibegin;
    if constexpr(sizeof(TCHAR) == 1) { 
        ibegin = s.find_first_not_of(" \t\r\n");
    }
    else {
        ibegin = s.find_first_not_of(L" \t\r\n");
    }
...
}
```

Comment: If you don't use preprocessor. `s.find_first_not_of(" \t\r\n")` and `s.find_first_not_of("L \t\r\n");` would both exist, that must be an error.

Comment: @Zhang Did you try to compile this?

Comment: Sorry, I just tried ... surprised it compiles...